# HTC Desire - where are my photos?

Tags: external-sd, htc-desire, htc

I was low on battery and my niece installed an app to assist (can not remember the name). However, she changed all my images onto my SD card. After that, I assumed I lost all my old images as I could not find them. :(

I removed my SD card to reset the phone and realized that one of the photos is showing under the gallery. Also, my screen saver is also an old photo now. However, I can not access the photo as it says to install the SD card. The problem is when I install the SD card, the images are not there anymore.

My niece does recall that she has changed something to say to save all the images onto the SD card, however she can not remember if it was on the phone or a part of the program. The issue is that I deleted the program when I realized I was still low on battery.

Is there somewhere on the HTC desire that I can change images from the SD card as I can not find it?

Answer (score 0):

As you removed the sd-card, you could use a card reader to attach it to your PC, which makes a search a lot easier. Usually, photos are stored below a folder called `dcim` on the card. Depending on the camera app (I don't have a Desire, so I cannot check that myself), subfolders there are named differently. On my phone, it uses a subfolder called "Camera". But there should not be too much subfolders there, so it will be easy to find.

If that's not the place where your niece placed the "old images", but as your Desire insists they are (somewhere else) on the card, you can use your file manager (I don't know what OS you are running on your PC) to search for `*.jpg` on the card -- that might match a lot of other images, but your photos should be listed along as long as they are on the card.